# How to shutdown a Hyperledger Fabric Network

Tags: hyperledger-composer

The tutorial at https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-guide.html is excellent in getting a simple network designed, deploying and running, but how do I shutdown this network and start it again without losing my assets and participants ??? There is not a single clue on how to do that.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a Developer environment (ie local env), then you can quiesce the docker container using `docker stop <container id>` - this will shutdown the container but upon `docker start <container id>` (assume you still have the same Fabric runtime and setup) you can resume interaction with the deployed business network and its data that you had added to it in the world state. For a Cloud environment, of course, it depends on where it is deployed and how the container is stopped, as well as other factors, so as to be able to restart from where you left off eg, a test environment with data in the business network registries, transaction history etc..

Answer (score 0):

The function that stops network or chaincode has not been implemented, so I think you have to remove your chaincode container by using command line manually at this time.

http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/chaincode4noah.html